# How to filter out even index values with array_filter?

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I'm trying to filter out values by their even index numbers, but it isn't going well.
$date is being return as the full array but with the last index missing. Is this because I'm using explode()?

Here's my code;

```
$route = "Dest A:0900:Dest B:0930:Dest C:1000";

$route_array = explode(":", $route);

foreach($route_array as $key){
    if(!($key & 1)){
        $date[] .= $key;
    }
}
return $date;
```

Comment: I assume that the reason is because you only want the times?

Comment: Well, ideally I'd like to seperate the destination from the times. I actually think I've figured out how to do it now that I've asked! Will post shortly. Maybe there's a more simple way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your loop should look like this

```
foreach($route_array as $k=>$key){
    if(($k+1)%2 == 0){
        $date[] = $key;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the problem:

```
foreach($route_array as $key)
```

You call the variable `$key`, but it will actually contain the value of that array element.

Instead, you should do the following:

```
foreach($route_array as $key => $value)
```

An then check wether the $key is odd or even.
Now $value will contain either the destination or the time.

Comment: Thanks for answering NicNLD. I ended up doing this in my final answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys...

Okay, so five minutes later I had a light bulb moment and came up with a solution;

```
$route = "Dest A:0900:Dest B:0930:Dest C:1000";
$route_array = explode(":", $route);

foreach($route_array as $key => $value){
    if(!($key & 1)){
        $date[] .= $route_array[$key];
    }
}
return $date;
```

Comment: This might work. However, the value of `$route_array[$key]` is already stored in `$value`, so why do you look it up again?

Comment: Yeah that's true, I've now amended my code to assign $value rather than $route_array[$key]. I'm a bit of a noob with PHP - thanks for the heads up.